# Laravel prooblem getting Auth user, manual login user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm trying to authenticate my and user via ajax using `axios` in my laravel and vuejs app. the authentication is working well and returning the auth user like this:

```
public function loginUser(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        $user = Auth::user();
         Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, TRUE);
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // The user is logged in successfully...
             return response()->json(Auth::id());
        }else{
            return response()->json("cannot chech user loggin user");
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json("failled authentication");
    }
}
```

This code is returning me the log's user id very well.  the problem is when I triying to retrieve the Auth user in other function, like this:

```
public function testAuth(Request $request){
        // return response()->json(Auth::user());
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // The user is logged in...
            return response()->json(Auth::user());
        }else{
            return response()->json("the user is not login");

        }
}
```

The result that Im getting is *"the user is not login"*
thank for help.

Comment: If Auth::attempt() returns true, the user is already logged in, so you don't have to to anything further, so I guess Auth::loginUsingId() is messing things up.

Comment: Can you share your routes file to hit those endpoints. Have you configured a middleware?

Comment: This seems to be a bit of code duplcation. Auth::attempt will log the user in automatically if it is successul. Just remove the "loginUsingId and the Auth::check and you should be fine. If you have the problem that your session is lost between the requests you might have problems with your setup. Are you running a webpack dev server using a proxy?

Comment: @FrankProvost yess I'm using the webpack and i want to log the user using API route, I thing the problem will be the session

Comment: Yess, I have log the user, but in the next request, when I tried to return it, it don't work! @Squiggs, I'm not using the middleware.

Comment: Thank very mush, I have resolve my problem by adding coping web configuration to my api configuration, to save the session after loggin!!! @FrankProvost

Comment: API does not use session. API uses token to authenticate user on every request

Comment: @Ts8060 I thing it is possible to overide it to use session. It 's just my idea! thank